# How do I go about displaying this information in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a rails app that tests some ports of a hostname I provide. This is what I have so far:

routes.rb:

```
Diagnostics::Application.routes.draw do
    match 'port_testing/test', :controller => :port_testing, :action=> :test
end
```

index.html.haml:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'user'

.spacey
  %h1 Port Testing
  = form_tag('port_testing/test', method: 'get') do
    = text_field_tag :hostname, 'localhost', size: 50
    - @models.each do |key,value|
      %input{:type=>"checkbox", :name=>"#{key}", :value=>1, :checked=>value}
      =key

    %input{:type => :submit, :value => "Test"}
```

port_testing_controller.rb:

```
require 'socket'

class PortTestingController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @models = {"80" => false, "443" => false, "2195" => true, "28009" => false}
    end
    def test
        puts "\n"

        hostname = params["hostname"]
        puts hostname

        ports = ["80", "443", "2195", "28009"]
        ports.each do |key|
            #puts key
            if params.has_key?(key)
                port = key.to_i
                is_port_open?(hostname, port)
            end
        end

        redirect_to("#/port_testing")
    end

    def is_port_open?(ip, port)
        begin
            Timeout::timeout(1) do
                begin
                    s = TCPSocket.new(ip, port)
                    puts "Successful"
                    s.close
                    return true
                rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
                    puts "Error"
                    return false
                end
        end
        rescue Timeout::Error
            puts "Timeout"
        end

        return false
    end
end
```

Right now, what I have works. I can put in a hostname in the text field, check which ports I want tested, and I get the results printed to the screen.

However, what I would like to do is to be able to save the most recent parameters I entered. Right now, after I click test, the page reloads so it resets to the default hostname and the default port. I would like it to keep the same hostname and port as I had before. How would I do this?

Also, I would like to have the results be put in a table and displayed on the same webpage. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should never print to the screen. To output information, you need to create a view file. For the test controller action the view file would be app/views/port_testing/test.html.haml. Put your table there. You'll have to create some instance variables in your controller, these will be available for use in your view.

For replacing the form with the host and ports, I suggest, in the controller action, saving the params to the session. Then use the session variables to set the values of your HTML inputs.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "saving the params to the session." Can you explain that more or link to some examples? Thanks.

Comment: The session should be available in your controller. It's a hash, so you can read and write to it like any other hash. In your controller action, you could save the hostname like this `session[:hostname] = params[:hostname]`. You can get that back out by accessing `session[:hostname]`. The session exists through page refreshes, so when you render the view, you can pull out the previously used values from the session and populate your inputs.